# Как в kivy сделать переход на другой экран при нажатии кнопки? А на втором экране будут кнопки. (Python)

Tags: python, kivy

Как в kivy сделать переход на другой экран при нажатии кнопки? А на втором экране будут кнопки. (Python)

Comment: посмотрите в первоисточнике https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

Answer (score 1):

Нашел такое решение:

```py
def next(self):
    self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
    self.manager.current = 'second'
```